# How to change the font of a select menus options using jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I currently have a select menu that is dynamically created using java script;

```
var rating = ["R","RR","RRR","RRRR","RRRRR"];
var SelectMenuBuild = '<select id="updateconditionselect">';

for (var i = 0; i < rating.length; i++) 
{
    SelectMenuBuild = SelectMenuBuild + "<option id='Condition' style='color: #eab92d; font-family: 'WebSymbolsRegular;' value='"+i+"'>"+rating[i]+"</option>";
};
SelectMenuBuild = SelectMenuBuild + "</option>";
```

[image]
Now the reason I use R's in the field options is that R in the font family WebSymbolsRegular,  R represents a star. So I am basically creating a drop down menu of stars from 1 to 5, the only problem is the font family isn't being applied to the drop down menu. The drop down menu keeps showing stars. I'm sure some how jQuery or jQuery Mobile is overriding this functionality and I'm sure how to get the font family to work.

By changing the code above:

```
'<select id="updateconditionselect" style='color: #eab92d; font-family: 'WebSymbolsRegular;'>';
```

it seemed to partially work. I now get the following:

Anyway of getting the select to show star instead of R?

Comment: id attributes should be unique otherwise you won't have a valid markup

Answer (score 0):

Try it like,

```
var rating = ["R","RR","RRR","RRRR","RRRRR"];
var SelectMenuBuild = '<select id="updateconditionselect" style="color: #eab92d; font-family: WebSymbolsRegular;">';

for (var i = 0; i < rating.length; i++) 
{
    SelectMenuBuild = SelectMenuBuild + "<option value='"+i+"'>"+rating[i]+"</option>";
};
SelectMenuBuild = SelectMenuBuild + "</select>";
```

No need to add `id` in `options`, also add `style attribute` to `select` not on `option`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That seemed to work, the drop down menu shows the stars but the selected item, the one that appears in the select menu is still show R and not a star. Any clue how to change that?

Answer (score 0):

Working jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/sEP3Y/

First select box must have an id so that its content can be changed with CSS.

Lets say this is a select box:

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="select-choice-custom" class="select">Shipping method:</label>
    <select name="select-choice-1" id="select-choice-custom" data-native-menu="false">
        <option value="standard">Standard: 7 day</option>
        <option value="rush">Rush: 3 days</option>
        <option value="express">Express: next day</option>
        <option value="overnight">Overnight</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

It has an id #select-choice-custom. When jQuery Mobile creates a select box it creates it from custom elements. There are 2 of them, one is button like custom select box that covers original select box. Second element is an option overlay.

Those 2 elements id generated from select id. Basically select box with an id **`#select-choice-custom`** will have 2 new elements **`#select-choice-custom-menu`** and **`#select-choice-custom-button`**. They have same name except both of them now have a new sulfix added to its name: **`-menu`** and **`-button`**.

Next step is forcing new font type on those elements, it can be done with this CSS:

```
#select-choice-custom-menu li div div a, #select-choice-custom-button .ui-btn-inner .ui-btn-text span {
    font-family: Calibri,Arial !important;
}
```

This is just an example, use your font instead of **`Calibri`**.

Comment: I have copy pasted your code an modified it. Now the problem I have is that it just affects the options and changes the fonts in the options menu and not the selected option. So I don't know if the font I'm using is causing a conflict with jquery?? Thanks so much for the help